# MySQL Error code 1005, SQL state HY000: Can't create table 'cpis.cpis_sudent_profile' (errno: 150)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need your assistance conditional! I could not determine what the problem is...
I think that everything is correct, but MySQL throws an error 1005, SQL state HY000: Can't create table 'cpis.cpis_sudent_profile' (errno: 150)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cpis_users`;
CREATE TABLE `cpis_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `activkey` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastvisit_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  `user_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cpis_countries`;
CREATE TABLE `cpis_countries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `title_ru` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_en` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_cz` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cpis_programs`;
CREATE TABLE `cpis_programs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_ru` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_ru` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_en` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_en` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_cz` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_cz` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `publicated` boolean DEFAULT false,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cpis_sudent_profile`;
CREATE TABLE `cpis_sudent_profile` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `citizenship` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `program_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`citizenship`) REFERENCES `cpis_countries` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `cpis_programs` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`member`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Simplify the code until the error goes away. Then review your last change. That will help you spotting the error. - For Stackoverflow, the requirement actually is, that you give the reduced as not further can be reduced example which demonstrates the problem. Pasting this wall of text of an SQL query is just slapping others into the face and often considered rude. See as well the help section.

Comment: Whilst agreeing with the above, the specific error you refer to is due to an incorrectly formed constraint.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html for details.  Perhaps the issue is that you have three different FKs referring to one PK (cpis_users(`id`)) in your section creating the cpis_student_profile table.  Try removing the last two constraints then putting them back one at a time.  See also all the similar questions ->>>> where this has been addressed before

Comment: I thank you for what you have allocated to me precious time!

Comment: Today I did not sleep for 20 hours, probably it is time to go to bed))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`program_id varchar(100)` should be of the same data type as `cpis_programs (id int(11))`. By having different types of data, failure to establish the constraint. Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a757e).

```
...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cpis_sudent_profile`;

CREATE TABLE `cpis_sudent_profile` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `citizenship` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  /*`program_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,*/
  `program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`citizenship`) REFERENCES `cpis_countries` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `cpis_programs` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `spfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`member`) REFERENCES `cpis_users` (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```